# DB performance of storing timestamp as Date vs Double [epoch]

Tags: performance, types, db2, timestamp, epoch

In DB2, I have to store records with granular level timestamps [microsec]. I went for double datatype and stored unix epoch time.

However, I need some recommendations from performance a standpoint of CRUD operations.

Note: My app doesn't need dates earlier than 1970.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that floating point numbers are an approximation? If for some reason you insist on using the epoch values as opposed to the `TIMESTAMP` datatype, you may want to consider using `BIGINT` instead.

Comment: Why are you using epoch anyway vs a normal timestamp?  DB2 stores a timestamp with microsecond precision in 10 bytes.

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for the suggestion. It's been working so far with DOUBLE, didn't face any approximations. However I'd take your suggestion if BIGINT can handle micro sec.

Comment: @ian-bjorhovde I chose epoch against normal timestamp, because it is much easier to go back and forth between unix, perl and DB2 and do some performance math as well as granular level reporting. It got me worried so I wanted to look for any known performance overhead of CRUD operations against TIMESTAMP and DOUBLE / BIGINT

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference for general CRUD. Any difference would probably show up if significant DATE/TIME operations are done such as needing many durations like "dates within last month" or "dates in 2010 through 2011". As long as there is no need to perform database date/time math or extract parts of timestamps for comparisons or presentation, I'd think performance should be reasonably equal. The BIGINT suggestion is a potential improvement though. (An unknown could be any potential additional time needed for however you create/retrieve a DOUBLE value for INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT.)